# load single object into a data store in sencha touch

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, sencha-touch, extjs

I'm trying to load a single json object using sencha touch.
When I work with arrays, all is well, but I havn't find a way of loading a single object into an Ext.data.Store

here is a sample of what I'm trying to load:

```
{"person":{"name":"John","surname":"Fox"}}
```

and it's not working.
after looking at [this](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?127700-JsonReader-problem-when-there-s-a-single-record) entry,

I tried to load the following and it worked:

```
[{"person":{"name":"John","surname":"Fox"}}]
```

My questions is: is there a way of loading it w/o the [ ]?
I had to modify my server side code in order to do this and it feels to me like a code smell...
I want to be able to load a single json object w/o putting it into a list.

here is my Sencha Touch proxy code:

```
Ext.regModel("Person", {
    fields: ['name','surname']

});

var store = new Ext.data.Store({


            model : "Person",
            autoLoad : true,

            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url : 'my json url...',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    record: 'person'
                }
            }
        });
```

BTW - my server side code is in Ruby on Rails.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**update**: the way to access a single json object using sencha is just to make a simple request and not use a data store. here is an example of code that does this:

```
Ext.ns('myNS');

Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'my url',
    method: 'GET',
    params: {
        someParam: 'someValue'
    },
    success: function(result, request) {
        var json = Ext.decode(result.responseText);
        myNS.loadedPerson = json.person;
    },
    failure: function(result, request) {
        Ext.Msg.alert('Error!', 'There was a problem while loading the data...');
    }
});
```

If you still insist on using a dataStore - here is a possible solution in the server side that maintains a restful API:
here is what I did in order to keep my API restful:

I added a new MIME type called sencha, that behaves exactly like json but it also wraps the json in [ ] parenthesis.

It might be (and probably is) an overkill, but this way it's not intrusive to my JSON API.
here is the code for the new MIME type:

```
Mime::Type.register_alias "application/json", :sencha

#Add the renderer, and register a responder:
require 'action_controller/metal/renderers'
require 'action_controller/metal/responder'

# This is also how Rails internally implements its :json and :xml renderers
# Rarely used, nevertheless public API
ActionController::Renderers.add :sencha do |json, options|
  json = ActiveSupport::JSON.encode(json) unless json.respond_to?(:to_str)
  # Add [ ] around the response
  json = "[#{json}]"
  json = "#{options[:callback]}(#{json})" unless options[:callback].blank?
  self.content_type ||= Mime::JSON
  self.response_body = json
end

# This sets up a default render call for when you do
# respond_to do |format|
#   format.sencha
# end
class ActionController::Responder
  def to_sencha
    controller.render :sencha => resource
  end
end
```

this allows me to define the following proxy (notice the format: 'sencha' ) in the client side:

```
proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        format: 'sencha',
        url :   my server url,
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            record: 'person'
        }
    }
```

This way I can still keep a restful API, and regard Sencha's json representation as another way of representing resources (i.e. json/xml/yaml)

Comment: YES! After THREE DAYS of banging my head into walls I finally get a result! Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

Animal from the Ext Development Team has given this very useful solution:

```
reader: {
    type: 'json',
    root: function(data) {
        if (data.users) {
            if (data.users instanceof Array) {
                return data.users;
            } else {
                return [data.users];
            }                    
        }                
    }
}
```

By simply using a function as root, you can make sure the reader gets the object in an array.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it's what you want, but you can load it through the model like:

```
var oneperson = new Person({id: anId});
```

When using a store you always have to send an array, even if it only has one record in it.
I don't know why always sending an array is problematic in your application, but it should be prette simple, just force the parameter to be an array...

```
persons = [*persons]
```

Comment: don't I need to specify the proxy in the model in order to load one person in the way you mentioned?
And it's problematic for me because making a single resource appear as an array by default is not RESTful and it messes up my json API...

Comment: Sorry, yes, you would have to set the proxy in the model.
I see where you are going on the RESTful, can't you use an action that returns many models? (for example index).
The thing here is that stores are for handling many records, so it's not logical to point it to a RESTful url that returns only one record (ie: show actions)

Comment: OK - can you please post an example using a single resource and a proxy in the model? It would really be helpful for me (This is what I'm trying to do now...)
I think that this is what I need

Comment: Just move the configuration of the proxy from the store to the model, it should work.

Comment: I could not get it to work, since it still expects an Array.
Personally, I don't think that it's possible...
I ended up adding a new responder type in my server side.
If you have a better solution, I would be happy to hear about it.
FYI - I tried to use:

 Ext.ModelMgr.getModel('Person').load(123, {
    success: function(person) {
        console.log(person.getId());
    }
});

Comment: And that made a call to a url like: "/persons/123", right? And Ext expects an array? If it does, it seems like a bug in Ext RESTful implementation...

Answer (score 0):

I agree with **iwiznia**, Ext.data.Store always waits for a [...] response, and probably you should change serverside code to return array of persons. 
Maybe you should also try to use REST style intraction of your serverside and client code.